# Kotlin Countdown How to do Minute:Seconds:MILLISECONDS

Tags: kotlin

I need to get macroseconds too. Like 10:59:(9,8,7,6...so fast)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post pictures of code. Instead copy-paste the code in a code block (between ```).
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1540818

Comment: what issue currently you are facing?

Comment: issue. I can't find any information how to do that. I have now only Hour:Minute:Second. But need Millisecond too

Comment: Isn't this more of math question than programming? Anyway, the remaining milliseconds would be what's left when you remove all the whole seconds, so `val milliseconds = time_in_milli_seconds % 1000`

Comment: unfortunnaly doesn't helped. It changes like default second timer. I need more faster than second. For example: 10second:9millisecond -> 10second:5millisecond

Comment: Then why did you set the interval to `1000` which means once per second?

Comment: Also, you pass a variable named `time_in_seconds` to a parameter that accepts milliseconds. It does not seem right. But this is another problem, not related to the one you have.